# Uber Eats Restaurant Menu in react-native

Tags: react-native

How to create a list view with top section header that staked on top like top taps?

I have tried to do that with section list without success , it stack only currently selected section where my requirement is to apply it just like uber eats[image]

Comment: Video tutorial on how to implement it: https://youtu.be/xutPT1oZL2M

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `Header` from [Native Base](https://nativebase.io/), using like that:

```
<Header hasTabs>
    <Left>...</Left>
    <Body>...</Body>
    <Right>...</Right>
</Header>

<Tabs>
    <Tab heading="Menu 1">
        <Component/> // you make a list or any things
    </Tab>
    <Tab>
    ...
    </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: thx @josecastollo86 good one , but the issue is to scroll vertically not horizontally , is this available on this library and how ?

Comment: You can use `FlatList` inside of `<Tab>`, or import a Component with the `FlatList` inside for understand better your code, you don't have any issue with the vertically scroll, its works for me.

Comment: does anyone know how to implement layout like this in android?

Answer (score 0):

try using react-native flatlist

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Answer (score 0):

Try using this libs

- https://github.com/georstat/react-native-synced-list
- https://github.com/bogoslavskiy/react-native-tabs-section-list

or build your owen with reanimated 2.

1. create an animated horizontal scrollview (for the custom header) and
   an animated SectionList (for the items)
2. add a handler to scroll the animated header to a specific index.listen for
3. viewable items change on the animated SectionList and
   attach the handler you built from step 2.